# Can I make cells fill in only after something is on the same line in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, format, highlighting

I am trying to make a spreadsheet in Excel 2013 that if data is entered on a line then the cells that don't have data in that line become highlighted.

I don't want to have the whole spreadsheet to be highlighted, just the lines that something has been entered on.

Is there formatting that allows this to happen?

Comment: `=AND(A1<>"",B1=""))` will return TRUE when A1 is not empty and B1 is.  You would change the cells to reference the ones you want.

Comment: Make a named formula called enabled, it checks if any cell has data. use conditional formatting to highlight blank cells. Then put a stop if true prior that uses a not(enabled) formula.  This will keep the blank cells turned off until something gets entered.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data from columns A to E. Select, for example, cell A2.

Go to Home -> Styles -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rules. Choose the 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'. The formula you want here is

```
=AND(COUNTA($A2:$E2)>0;ISBLANK(A2))
```

The trick here is the $ symbol, to make it an absolute reference. What we want is a relative reference, so do not put it before the row numbers and since you want to highlight only the blank cells, do not put in the reference of the `ISBLANK` function. The idea of the formula is to check if the entire row has any data (`COUNTA($A2:$E2)`) and look for only the blanks.

After typing in the formula, just click OK. Copy cell A2 and select all your data on the table and Paste Special -> Formats. This copies the conditional formatting to all your data.

Comment: You can also select your entire range before applying the conditional formatting. You don't need to copy then later, but you have to be careful when typing in the formula. Excel automatically adds the $ symbol, to make all references absolute, but you need a relative reference for this to work.